# Set of numbers divisible by both 2 and 3?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two sets of numbers:

$$\ A = \{n \in \Bbb{N}\;| \; n=2m \;\mathrm{where} \;   m \in \Bbb{N}\}$$

$$\ B = \{n \in \Bbb{N}\;  |\;  n=3m \;\mathrm{where} \;  m \in  \Bbb{N}\}$$

I am looking for the set of numbers in the union $\ A\cup B$. I can see that this set of numbers must be divisible by either 2, 3 or both. How can I form a general expression for this?

Comment: What numbers are not in your set?

Comment: What have you tried? Also the title of your Post asks for something different than the body of your post.

Answer (score 1):

$$A \cup B =  \{n \in \Bbb{N}\;| (n = 2m \vee n = 3m) ~\text{where}~m \in \Bbb{N} \}$$